# jQuery responds with html table containing a (form in each row plus jquery code to edit each row) newly created forms ignore submit()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Three days and I cannot find an answer to this or a solution. I am far from being a jQuery guy.

User arrives at a php page that shows a form to choose the language code and submit. Form gets submitted and the jQuery response builds a table in a div container in the original page. So far so good. The resulting table contains hundreds of rows where the language variables can be edited. On clicking the edit button, I get nothing, no errors in console, nothing. If I use on click, I can fire an alert. On submit, bind, and many others do not work.

I am attempting to load the table, perform basic editing, submit the edits to the db, and refresh the div.table.row with the edited results. I have not gotten to the part where I refresh the rows with the edited data, still stuck trying to submit the dynamic form in each row.

One interesting thing that happens when I use on click, it works with just the first button I click on, it somehow disables all the other rows. I need to be able to submit a row for changes, have that row refresh and move on to the next row all without redirecting. Is this too much to ask? Or should I just move them from page to page?

The ajax php page returns the table using the following code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['edit_language']) && $_POST['edit_language'] == 1){
    edit_language($_POST['lang']); //call function to edit language
} else {
    echo "You got here but no variables<br>"; //testing
    print_r($_POST); //testing
}

function edit_language($lang){  
//query table to get language vars list
    $sql = "SELECT lang_site.lid, lang_codes.iso_code, lang_codes.`language`, lang_varnames.varid, lang_varnames.varname, lang_site.varval FROM lang_codes LEFT JOIN lang_site ON lang_site.langid = lang_codes.langid LEFT JOIN lang_varnames ON lang_site.varid = lang_varnames.varid where lang_codes.iso_code = '" . $lang . "'";
    $result = db_query($sql);
//generate report table
    echo "<table cellspacing='0' border='1'><tr><th>Count</th><th>Language</th><th>Variable Id</th><th>Variable Name</th><th>Variable Value</th><th>Edit</th></tr>";
    $a=1; //count the rows to number the rows for easy viewing
    while($data = db_fetch_assoc($result)){
//create form in each tr
        echo "<form name='edit_" . $data['lid'] . "' id='edit_" . $data['lid'] . "' action=''><tr><td>" . $a++ . "</td><td>" . $data['language'] . "</td><td>" . $data['varid'] . "</td><td>" . $data['varname'] . "</td><td><textarea class='form-control' name='varval' id='varval' cols='100' wrap='virtual'>" . $data['varval'] . "</textarea></td><td id='editresponse'><button type='submit' class='button' type='submit' id='but_" . $data['lid'] . "'>Edit</button></td></tr></form>";
?>
//jquery to post edits
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {    //using $.ajax() function
        //alert("document ready"); //this alerts each row

//this function will not work, no errors, simply nothing
            $(document).on("submit", "#edit_<?php echo $data["lid"]; ?>", function(e)
            {
        //alert("button clicked");  //this does not work
                    var data = $("#edit_<?php echo $data["lid"]; ?>").serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url  : "/lang/ajax_langs.php",
                        data : data,
                        success :  function(response)
                        {       
                            {
                                $("#editresponse").html(response);                    
                            };  
                        }
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
    </script>
<?php
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

How do I get the jQuery to submit the individual form in each row to effect an edit and then refresh each row individually as languages are edited? I need to add another form to each row to delete an entry then remove the row dynamically, but I am stuck here without being able to submit any of these forms.

I should add that this generated form shows well in the website, but is not shown in view source. Using chrome browser. I'm open to any suggestions. Thanks in advance for reading. I seriously hope I can find a solution here. Otherwise, I'm back to the 90's on this software.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my question that I'm getting no answers?

Comment: I want to thank everyone for their help, it seems user vbudo is the only one who made any attempts at answering my question, so I will mark it as answered and upvote him. And I'll just go back to lurking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you are only submitting one id.  You need to make each of your forms be of the same class. Therefore, any form clicked will be processed. Like

```
<form class="myForm" .....
```

Then, the Jquery would look like this

```
$(".myForm").submit(function(e){
 var inputToChange = this.varval; // saw input varVal, but use whatev
 var dataToChange = inputToChange.value;
 // then send the data to php for processing using ajax or post
```

Then, use inputToChange.value = whatever new value you want to put into the form input or other div/td etc. you want to change. If you want to change data that isn't in an input, just make that td a text input and disable it from being edited by the client

```
<input type="text" name="lname" disabled>
```

then on callback send new data to this.lname.value = (many other ways to do this as well)

Don't forget, if you send through ajax you want to stop the form itself from submitting so use e.preventDefault()

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just tried that and still get nothing. Not even an error. I had tried that initially, but there are hundreds of rows, I would have thought I needed to make sure each form had it's own identifier as to not mix up any forms.